# Codeblocks -pg and -g not Producing gmon.out OpenGl

Tags: c, opengl

I wrote a C program using opengl, I tried to profile it, and kept getting no profile data found.

I disabled all flags except -pg and -g (from the options) and -std=c99 & -Iinclude (from "Other Options").

I tried putting pg and g in my build options for all targets, I tried putting -pg in the linker, I changed my programing to simply return 0; incase exiting was an issue.

What makes me suspect OpenGl is that I opened a previous project (that used graphics.h - the flags of which are still in the linker, idk if thats an issue) and ran it with the same flags and everything, and it worked fine.

I read just about every page on google, but nothing turns up if I include opengl in the search :/

Comment: You need to specify `-pg` on both compiling and linking phases, and correctly `exit` your program (i.e. no crashes). I no longer use gprof (switched to callgrind and oprofile) but it worked quite fine for GL programs before, and I can't really see any valid reason for it not to. If you still have problems, add full build command list to the question (and if you're not sure which commands gets executed, try to reproduce it yourself in a terminal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working directory was in a random place (outside the project) so gmon.out could not be found.
"Project -> Properties -> Build targets -> Execution working dir"

Correcting the directory fixed the problem.